# Logging python change log level text

Tags: python, logging

with the library

`import logging`

when I use the method `.error(text)` or `.warning(text)`, the logger writes the log level as INFO, WARNING, ERROR, etc.

I was wondering if there is a way to change the `WARNING` string, for example, to `WARN` (and change `ERROR` as `ERR`, instead).

TLDR; 
I want to change the Text logging level for the message  ('DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL') in whatever I like... Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That comes out of the box in the `logging` module, with the `addLevelName` function:

```
logging.addLevelName(logging.WARNING, "WARN")
logging.addLevelName(logging.ERROR, "ERR")
```

Those name will be used by all the formatters.